# Addclass if length % 3 == 1 or == 2

Tags: jquery, list, each, modulo

I have a several grids listed by 3 items per rows, and I need to addClass to the last item if in the last row there is only 1 item or addClass to the 'before last' item if there are 2 items in the last row.

see below:

```js
$('.row').each(function(){
  if ($('.item').length % 3 == 2){
    $(this).find('.item').last().addClass('col-lg-offset-4');
  } else if ($('.item').length % 3 == 1){
    $(this).find('.item').last().prev().addClass('col-lg-offset-2');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Can you help me with this? What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: if ($('.item').length % 3 == 2){  use $(this) before item for particular row

Comment: I don't know why, every code looks good for me... but every time I got 'col-lg-offeset-4' for the last item, even when there are 5 items in the list....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine the only problem is that while iterating each .row div you are looking for

```
$('.item').length
```

which will actually look for all divs with class .item in the whole page not only the existing row you are inside, solution is to find the items inside that specific row div by using

```
$(this).find('.item').length
```

so your code should be

```
$('.row').each(function(){
  var itemsCount = $(this).find('.item').length;
  if (itemsCount % 3 == 2){
     $(this).find('.item').last().addClass('col-lg-offset-4');
  } else if (itemsCount % 3 == 1){
     $(this).find('.item').last().prev().addClass('col-lg-offset-2');
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes it was my problem, I could'nt solve it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.row').each(function(){
  if ($(this).find('.item').length % 3 == 2){
    $(this).find('.item').last().addClass('col-lg-offset-4');
  } else if ($(this).find('.item').length % 3 == 1){
    $(this).find('.item').last().prev().addClass('col-lg-offset-2');
  }
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/c0dhzqfs/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I haven't tested it, but should give you a hint.

```
$('.row').each(function(){
    // Calculate Last Item Count
    var lastItem = $(this).find('.item').last();
    var lastItemCount = lastItem.length
    // I need to addClass to the last item if in the last row there is only 1 item
    if (lastItemCount == 1) {
        lastItem.addClass('col-lg-offset-4');
    }
    // or addClass to the 'before last' item if there are 2 items in the last row.
    if (lastItemCount == 2) {
        lastItem.prev().addClass('col-lg-offset-2');
    }
});
```

Comment: but I have not only one row.. I have several row and in each row I have a list of items

Comment: I think it's good but it misses an "else if" in the code otherwise it gives the 2 classes.. thanks anyway

Comment: Personally I avoid nested if, anycase both the approach works.